# Loss function for Bounding Box Regression using CNN

Tags: regression, theano, bounding-box, loss

I am trying to understand Loss functions for Bounding Box Regression in CNNs. Currently I use Lasagne and Theano, which makes writing loss expressions very easy. Many sources propose different methods and I am asking myself which one is usually used in practice.

The bounding boxes coordinates are represented as normalized coordinates in the order `[left, top, right, bottom]` (using `T.matrix('targets', dtype=theano.config.floatX)`).

I have tried the following functions so far; however all of them have their drawbacks.

### Intersection over Union

I was adviced to use the `Intersection over Union` measure to identify how well the 2 bounding boxes align and overlap. However, a problem occurs when the boxes don't overlap and then intersection is 0; then the whole quotient turns 0 regardless of how far the bounding boxes are apart. I implemented it as:

```
def get_area(A):
    return (A[:,2] - A[:,0]) * (A[:,1] - A[:,3])

def get_intersection(A, B):
    return (T.minimum(A[:,2], B[:,2]) - T.maximum(A[:,0], B[:,0])) \
        * (T.minimum(A[:,1], B[:,1]) - T.maximum(A[:,3], B[:,3]))

def bbox_overlap_loss(A, B):
    """Computes the bounding box overlap using the
    Intersection over union"""
    intersection = get_intersection(A, B)
    union = get_area(A) + get_area(B) - intersection
    # Turn into loss
    l = 1.0 - intersection / union
    return l.mean()
```

### Squared Diameter Difference

To create an error measure for non overlapping bounding boxes, I tried to compute the squared difference of the bounding box diameter. It seems to work, but I almost sure that there is much better way to do this. I implemented it as:

```
def squared_diameter_loss(A, B):
    # Represent the squared distance from the real diameter
    # in normalized pixel coordinates
    l = (abs(A[:,0:2]-B[:,0:2]) + abs(A[:,2:4]-B[:,2:4]))**2
    return l.mean()
```

### Euclidean Loss

The simplest function would be the `Euclidean Loss` which computes the square root of the difference of the bounding box parameters squared. However, this doesn't take into account the area of the overlapping bounding box but only the difference of the parameters left, right, top, bottom. I implemented it as:

```
def euclidean_loss(A, B):
    l = lasagne.objectives.squared_error(A, B)
    return l.mean()
```

Could someone guide me on which would be the best loss function for bounding box regression for this use case or spot if I am doing something wrong here. Which loss function is usually used in practice?

Comment: Side note: I don't think your IOU works. You can calculate IOU with shapely and it gives a different answer (0.33 vs 0.4).
    `boxA=shapely.geometry.box(0,0,10,5);boxB=shapely.geometry.box(5,0,10,10);iou = boxA.intersection(boxB).area/boxA.union(boxB).area`

Comment: This paper has a nicely designed differentiable IoU loss function: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.01471.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from personal implementation experience, I had much better results training a CNN using IOU as the loss function as opposed to Euclidean (MSE or L2) Loss. Have not used the squared diameter difference loss. In general, a loss function that explicitly represents the goodness of your outputs for the tasks you hope to accomplish is probably best.

With regards to the IOU having a value of zero, you can introduce some additional term in the formulation so that it gracefully trends towards 0, perhaps based on normalized distance between bbox centers. This might give the additional effect of helping to center bounding boxes relative to the ground truth.

This response is mostly conceptual but I'd be happy to supply code examples if desired.

Answer (score 0):

For IoU loss, GIoU can solve your problem : https://giou.stanford.edu/